# Text being shortened

Tags: xcode, jquery-mobile, mobile, ios-simulator

I have the following code but I am unsure why when I use the Xcode iPhone simulator its showing the ... why? or is it because I am using the simulator

I am using the jQuery Graphite Theme

**Issue:**

[image: Screenshot if issue]

**HTML:**

```
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1 class="appTitle">Birthday Reminders</h1>
        </div><!-- Header -->
```

**CSS:**

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px)
{
.appTitle { max-width:100%; font-size:12px; text-align: center;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/GFfAt/

**CSS used :**

```
.appTitle {
    margin: 0.6em 15% 0.8em !important;
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

15% inside a margin is a left/right space between text and app header limits.

Don't lower font size because header height will decrees, to counter it increase margin.